# Trying to understand If statements when trying to incorporate user Input

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner - like I'm Today-years-old with this.

So I'm mucking about with a silly little piece of code to try and help me understand If statements:

```
print ('How many sausages have you eaten today?')
userInput = ('>5' or '<5')
if userInput input == int ('> 5'):
    print ('Whoa! Slow down Fatty!')
elif userInput input == ('< 5'):
    print ('Ok, but better call it a day now')
```

I'm trying to alter the printed message based on how many sausages the user inputs - e.g. above 5 or below 5.
I know that I'm doing something (probably many things) wrong.
Can anyone help to tidy this up?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the number of sausages is 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a fixed version:**

There is some notes to help you understand

```
# To get an input you need to use input()
userInput = input('How many sausages have you eaten today?')
# Turn the input from text to a number with int()
userInput = int(userInput)
if userInput > 5:
    print ('Whoa! Slow down Fatty!')
elif userInput < 5:
    print ('Ok, but better call it a day now')
```

Comment: Thank you!! This makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems. First, you cannot use `int()` to get user input. Instead, you must use `input()`. Second, you cannot convert inequalities into integers. Like this:

```
print('How many sausages have you eaten today?')
userInput = int(input())
if userInput > 5:
    print('Whoa! Slow down Fatty!')
else:
    print('Ok, but better call it a day now')
```

Notice how I get user input with `input()`, which will return a string. Then, I convert it to an integer with `int()`. If the user inputs something that is not an integer, then the program will crash because the input to `int()` must be able to be converted into an integer.

In the if-else statement, I check if `userInput`, which is an integer, is greater than 5. I also used an `else` statement, not an `elif`, because if `userInput` is exactly 5 then neither statement would have been true.

Comment: THANK YOU!! It works. I was overthinking this!